# Information on LTSpice switching regulator macromodels?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, modeling

I have read this [Design Note 12](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/design-notes/dn012f.pdf) from Linear Technologies titled “An Op Amp SPICE Macromodel”. I was wondering if there is similar technical information about the macromodels of **switching regulators** (buck, boost and so on). Does someone know if there is some specification about what really is modelled in these macromodels?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The models are usually inspectable I believe but will you know what the various code lines mean?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority, if not all of the switching regulators are encrypted. If you want to model such devices, then your best friends will be the A-devices and the VCSW.

Also, that opamp model, even if written by Jung, is not very relevant to what LTspice models use, since the "cornerstone" (word used by Mike Engelhardt) of almost all of the opamp models is the `[SpecialFunction]/OTA`. You can easily verify this since a lot of the opamp models are not encrypted.